# Force WPF to Commit Changes on Focused Element

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, data-binding, visual-studio-2010, commit

I'm working with VS2010, WPF and EF.  I've placed controls on my window by dragging an entity out of the Data Sources toolwindow.  I used the "details" setting so my entity is represented by several labels and textboxes.  I've also added a button with the following code:

```
_context.SaveChanges();
```

When I'm editing data, the changes in whichever textbox has focus are not committed back to the DB.  Everything else commits just fine.  If I shift focus to another element prior to hitting the save button, it commits as well.  I've experienced the same thing with the DataGrid.

I know I'm missing something simple, but I can figure it out.  Any ideas on what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because TextBox's default Binding UpdateSourceTrigger is LostFocus.  If you modify all your Bindings to set this to PropertyChanged, it will work like you expect:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

Comment: Why doesn't the TextBox "lose focus" when the button is clicked? Can you programatically force this?

Comment: Can anybody answer Rob Fonseca-Ensor's question?

Comment: It does lose focus when the button is clicked.  Unfortunately, it is AFTER the button is clicked, and its command/click handler executed. The effect is that the binding isn't updated until after the button's action is executed.  You can get the BindingExpression and force it to update the source before executing the button's action if that is a requirement.  Generally though, setting the UpdateSourceTrigger is the easiest way.

Comment: This won't work if your properties don't implement IPropertyChanged.

Comment: WPF will happily do a two-way binding to properties on classes that don't implement that interface. Your class's properties will get set by the TextBox. What you won't see are changes to the UI if the properties are set in code, or other UI elements if multiple elements are bound to the same property and one changes. This MSDN article provides more detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this same issue when trying to set the value of a databound TextBox programmatically, but Abe's suggestion didn't work for our setup (it was causing some erratic validation behavior).

Here's how I got it to work:

```
TextBox tb = (TextBox)this.FindName("TargetTextBox");
tb.Text = "1234";
tb.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
```